# SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

I'm trying to configure the development environment for a homework. I've installed Apache Maven, Apache Tomcat and Eclipse Juno (Java EE), and the needed plugin. I've followed the wiki provided with the code of the project. The sources are imported via SVN. I've installed all the missing libraries and I've set the classpaths. However, when I select Run on server, I always get this error:

```
Mar 25, 2013 3:32:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.22.
Mar 25, 2013 3:32:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Mar 25, 2013 3:32:18 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Mar 25, 2013 3:32:18 PM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
Mar 25, 2013 3:32:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1153 ms
Mar 25, 2013 3:32:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 25, 2013 3:32:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.32
Mar 25, 2013 3:32:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor ephemere.xml
Mar 25, 2013 3:32:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class  org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/scannotation/AnnotationDB$CrossReferenceException
at      org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap.contextInitialized(ResteasyBootstrap.java:26)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4205)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4704)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1315)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  org.scannotation.AnnotationDB$CrossReferenceException
at  org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
... 25 more
ServletContextListener started
Mar 25, 2013 3:32:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Mar 25, 2013 3:32:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/ephemere] startup failed due to previous errors
ServletContextListener destroyed
Mar 25, 2013 3:32:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class  org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap.contextDestroyed(ResteasyBootstrap.java:38)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4244)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4879)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1315)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Mar 25, 2013 3:32:19 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader  clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/ephemere] appears to have started a thread named [pool-1-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Mar 25, 2013 3:32:19 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Mar 25, 2013 3:32:19 PM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
Mar 25, 2013 3:32:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 670 ms
```

I've already installed the scannotation library but nothing seems to change. In addition, I guess there's nothing wrong with pom.xml and also with ephemere.xml, since all other students haven't encountered this problems.

Comment: "I've already installed the scannotation library" ... How did you install it ? in your maven repository ? in the eclipse project ?

Comment: in my maven repo through: 
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=scannotation-1.0.2.jar -DgroupId=org.scannotation -DartifactId=scannotation -Dversion=1.0.2 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true

Comment: Did you try to run something like "update maven dependencies" in eclipse (I don't know how to run it because I don't use eclipse, but I know it exists and it often solve strange bugs in eclipse-maven integration).